# Querying a spark streaming application from spark-shell (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am following this [example](http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/438089/notebooks/spark2.0/Structured%20Streaming%20using%20Python%20DataFrames%20API.html) in the `pyspark` console and everything works perfectly.

After that I wrote it as an PySpark application as follows:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

import click

import logging

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.types import *


@click.command()
@click.option('--master')
def most_idiotic_bi_query(master):
    spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .master(master)\
            .appName("stream-test")\
            .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')

    some_schema = ....  # Schema removed 

    some_stream    = spark\
                     .readStream\
                     .option("sep", ",")\
                     .schema(some_schema)\
                     .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)\
                     .csv("/data/some_stream", header=True)

    streaming_counts = (
        linkage_stream.groupBy(some_stream.field_1).count()
    )

    query = streaming_counts.writeStream\
                            .format("memory")\
                            .queryName("counts")\
                            .outputMode("complete")\
                            .start()



    query.awaitTermination()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    most_idiotic_bi_query()
```

The app is executed as:

```
spark-submit test_stream.py --master spark://master:7077
```

Now, If I open a new spark driver in another terminal:

```
pyspark --master spark://master:7077
```

And try to run:

```
spark.sql("select * from counts")
```

It fails with:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-732b22f02ef6> in <module>()
----> 1 spark.sql("select * from id_counts").show()

/usr/spark-2.0.2/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    541         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    542         """
--> 543         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    544 
    545     @since(2.0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/py4j-0.10.4-py3.4.egg/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/spark-2.0.2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: 'Table or view not found: counts; line 1 pos 14'
```

I don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. If you check [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks) for memory sink:

> The output is stored in memory as an in-memory table. Both, Append and Complete output modes, are supported. This should be used for debugging purposes on low data volumes as the entire output is collected and **stored in the driver’s memory**. Hence, use it with caution.

As you can see memory sink doesn't create a persistent table or global temporary view but a local structure limited to a driver. Hence it cannot be queried from another Spark application.

So the memory output has to be queried from the driver, in which it is written. For example you could mimic `console` mode as shown below.

A dummy writer:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tempfile
import shutil

def producer(path):
    temp_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    def producer(i):
        df = pd.DataFrame({
          "group": np.random.randint(10, size=1000)
        }) 
        df["val"] = (
            np.random.randn(1000) + 
            np.random.random(1000) * df["group"] + 
            np.random.random(1000) * i % 7
        )
        f = tempfile.mktemp(dir=temp_path)
        df.to_csv(f, index=False)
        shutil.move(f, path)
    return producer
```

Spark application:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, DoubleType, StructType, StructField

schema = StructType([
   StructField("group", IntegerType()),
   StructField("val", DoubleType())
])

path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
query_name = "foo"

stream = (spark.readStream
    .schema(schema)
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load(path))

query = (stream
    .groupBy("group")
    .avg("val")
    .writeStream
    .format("memory")
    .queryName(query_name)
    .outputMode("complete")
    .start())
```

And some events:

```py
from rx import Observable

timer = Observable.timer(5000, 5000)
timer.subscribe(producer(path))
timer.skip(1).subscribe(lambda *_: spark.table(query_name).show())

query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: excellent answer. Thank you for the explanation. Just one question Which will be the correct answer for doing what I want to achive? `query` will write to parquet? And in the other driver, create a temporal table?

Comment: Writing to file seems like the way to go. There is custom `foreach` sink, but it is not supported in Python yet.