# Pyspark shell unusable while stream is running

Tags: apache-spark, cmd, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I just began exploring Apache Spark (following [A gentle introduction to Apache Spark](http://go.databricks.com/gentle-intro-spark)) under Windows 10, using `pyspark`. I got to the chapter about Structured Streaming, and I'm having a bit of trouble with `cmd` - whenever I start a stream, the `cmd` window becomes unusable, because Spark keeps "typing" stuff so even if I do type anything, it quickly disappears.

My code (taken directly from the book):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import window, column, desc, col

staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")\
.option("header", "true")\
.option("inferSchema", "true")\
.load("./data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")

staticSchema = staticDataFrame.schema

streamingDataFrame = spark.readStream\
.schema(staticSchema)\
.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)\
.format("csv")\
.option("header", "true")\
.load("./data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")

purchaseByCustomerPerHour = streamingDataFrame\
.selectExpr(
"CustomerId",
"(UnitPrice * Quantity) as total_cost" ,
"InvoiceDate" )\
.groupBy(
col("CustomerId"), window(col("InvoiceDate"), "1 day"))\
.sum("total_cost")

purchaseByCustomerPerHour.writeStream\
.format("memory")\
.option('checkpointLocation','F:/Spark/sparktmp')\
.queryName("customer_purchases")\
.outputMode("complete")\
.start()
```

The issue I'm talking about:

[image: My issue with cmd]

The caret should be at the line where [Stage 6:======>] is. So if I wanted to query the stream (like the book suggests) I am unable to. And I cannot just open a second `pyspark` shell, since that would be a different Spark session. I'm also not sure whether the streaming job should start over when it exhausts all the input files ones (which it does) but I guess that's a topic for a different question.

Let me know if I should provide more information. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**  Just use notebook environment. [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) (optionally with [Apache Toree](https://toree.apache.org/) kernel) or [Apache Zeppelin Notebook](http://zeppelin.apache.org/), will work just fine and won't capture the output (this might be undesired [How to get the output from console streaming sink in Zeppelin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47357418/8371915)), and allow you to make uninterrupted queries.

In standard shell setting `spark.ui.showConsoleProgress` to `false` can also help a bit:

```
bin/pyspark --conf "spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false"
```